# Proof of Contour Integral along Reversed Contour explanation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The following is provided as a proof on proofwiki.org, but I am not sure how the author went from line 2 to line 3 of their proof. If $u=\psi(t)$ then $\frac{du}{dt}=\psi'(t)$ implying that we can make the substitution $dt=\frac{1}{\psi'(t)}du$ into line 2, so I'm not sure where the minus sign in line 3 comes from. I see that $\psi'(t)=-1$, but surely this doesn't matter if we make that substitution for $dt$? I think I'm missing something obvious here, any help would be really appreciated.
[image]

Comment: When making the substitution you end up with $\int_b^a$ which is then changed to $-\int_a^b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expanding comment by* @Diger.

In line 2 the integral in $t$ is taken from $t=a$ to $b$, while the integral in $u=\psi(t)$ is taken from $u=\psi(a)=b$ to $\psi(b)=a$. But $dt=-du$. So

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int_{t=a}^{b}f\left( \gamma \left( \psi \left( t\right) \right)
\right) \gamma ^{\prime }\left( \psi \left( t\right) \right) \,\psi ^{\prime
}\left( t\right) \,dt\quad\text{in line 2}, \\
&=&-\int_{t=a}^{b}f\left( \gamma \left( \psi \left( t\right) \right) \right)
\gamma ^{\prime }\left( \psi \left( t\right) \right) \,dt,\quad \psi \left(
t\right) =a+b-t,\psi ^{\prime }\left( t\right) =-1, \\
&=&\int_{u=\psi \left( a\right) =b}^{\psi \left( b\right) =a}f\left( \gamma
\left( u\right) \right) \gamma ^{\prime }\left( u\right) \,du,\qquad u=\psi
\left( t\right) ,du=\psi ^{\prime }\left( t\right) dt=-dt, \\
&=&-\int_{u=a}^{b}f\left( \gamma \left( u\right) \right) \gamma ^{\prime
}\left( u\right) \,du,\quad\text{in line 3}. 
\end{eqnarray*}